# How to display a result of a decryption on a webpage so that malicious extensions or MiMers don't have enough time?

Tags: encryption, privacy, man-in-the-middle, decryption

As it says on the tin.

I'd like to build something akin to a privnote clone, except I want to be 100% sure of the code, me having to write it and all. I the link contains the decryption key, there's only so many ways so see what the output is, right?

I've once realized I had malware on my computer since google's SSL certificate was signed by `Potato Farmers Collective` or some such so I don't trust HTTPS all that much; it has to be something clever like flash.

Should I output an image? Should I have flash output the image? Would pre-agreeing on a pig lating-style cypher in real life make it easier?

Will both parties pre-agreeing on a key as well somehow make it safer? Seems like it'd make any but the very first communication unsafe: ISP logs, etc.

We're just paranoid androids, no shenanigans.

Thanks

Comment: There is really no way to do what you're asking. If the machine can decrypt the data and display it to the user, so can malware see and extract that data. I guess you could make it so decryption happens out-of-band on a separate trusted device (the compromised machine displays encrypted data and the user has to type it in manually into the trusted device for decryption) but that would be a huge usability problem.

Comment: @AndréBorie Luckily. usability is not an issue here. (Surprising). If you'd like to type it up as an answer in more detail I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is untrusted then you should not give that machine any way to decrypt the data. It should simply forward the encrypted data to a trusted entity (another computer, a superhero that can do TLS in his head, etc) and let that entity decrypt it - of course you'd then have the problem of securing that entity itself.

You could use a dedicated computer only to access the sensitive data, possibly behind a hardware firewall that blocks any traffic not related to the site you want to access (to block incoming attacks or accidiental attempts to browse other sites that could be less secure and serve malware).